# Trying to Get A Array of Transformations to Store Orientation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working on a for fun project where I going to code multiplayer snake.

I've created two Prefabs within Unity called "SnakeBodyHorizontal" and "SnakeBodyVertical". The goal is to change the a segment of the snake depending on the orientation with the correct prefab. If the snake body is moving down/up, I use Snake body horizontal. If the snake body is moving left/right, I want to use the vertical prefab. By default the snake body is horizontal.

My issue: I'm struggling hardcore making all snake body segment always the correct orientation depending on the direction they're moving, as shown in the example image.

My Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Snake : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector2 _direction = Vector2.right;
    private List<Transform> _segments = new List<Transform>();
    private KeyCode lastHitKey = KeyCode.D;

    public Transform segmentPrefab;
    public int initialSize = 3;

    //sprites for snake head 
    public Sprite SnakeHeadUp;
    public Sprite SnakeHeadRight;
    public Sprite SnakeHeadLeft;
    public Sprite SnakeHeadDown;

    private void Start()
    {
        ResetState();
    }


    // Update: Updated Once Per Time (Edit -> Project Settings -> Time (0.09) to change difficulty!)
    // This function is controlling the direction our snake moves.
    void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.S)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadUp;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.W;
            _direction = Vector2.up; 

        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.W)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadDown;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.S;
            _direction = Vector2.down;
            
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.D)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadLeft;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.A;
            _direction = Vector2.left;

        } else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.A)
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadRight;
            lastHitKey = KeyCode.D;
            _direction = Vector2.right;
        }
    }

    //This transforms the position of our snake head, rounded to a whole number. This should force our snake to move in a grid.
    //if a segment has the same x value as the previous segment, it must be cos turnt!!! then change segments sprite
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {

        for (int i = _segments.Count - 1; i > 0; i--){
            _segments[i].position = _segments[i - 1].position;
        }

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(
            Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.x) + _direction.x,
            Mathf.Round(this.transform.position.y) + _direction.y,
            0.0f
        );  
    }

    //Function handles the logic of iterating in reverse from a list of prefabs of our snake segments, to create a new snake segment.
    private void Grow()
    {
        Transform segment = Instantiate(this.segmentPrefab);
        segment.position = _segments[_segments.Count - 1].position; //each segment inherits position

        _segments.Add(segment);
    }

    //Function handles the logic of resetting the state of our game upon collision with objects other than food
    private void ResetState(){

        //emptying the snakelist
        for(int i = 1; i < _segments.Count; i++)
        {
            Destroy(_segments[i].gameObject);
        }

        _segments.Clear();
        _segments.Add(this.transform);

        //resetting our snake from 1 back to initialsize (3)
        for(int i = 1; i < this.initialSize; i++)
        {
            _segments.Add(Instantiate(this.segmentPrefab));
            //initalizing the original segments
            _segments[i].position = new Vector3(
            -50.0f,
            0.0f,
            0.0f
        );
        }

        this.transform.position = new Vector3(
            -5.0f,
            0.0f,
            0.0f
        );
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Food")
        {
            Grow();
        }
        else if (other.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            ResetState();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example of Problem]

I attempted to rotate the prefab sprite I am using depending on if the previous arrays x value was not the same as the current one, if the X values aren't the same, then it has moved vertically. However this implementation was very buggy. So better suggestions would be nice

Comment: Instead of using multiple prefabs, you could use a single prefab that includes functionality to calculate which sprite to use based on the position of adjacent segments. e.g., if segment `i-1` is to the left and segment `i+1` is to the right then use the horizontal sprite. You would need to access adjacent segments, which you could do without even needing to track them in a collection using their transform sibling index (assuming all segments are parented to another object). Just an idea, I was thinking of doing a similar project and this is how I was planning to implement it.

Comment: it won't work this way anyway ... what about the corners? I would also go with @rshepp 's suggestion  - you basically have 6 cases to check and use 6 different sprites/meshes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using something I'd call "TurningPoints". Basically whenever you change direction, you save the point where you have to turn and which direction. Then whenever a segment reaches this point, you turn it according to the saved direction. In your case, you don't have to actually track a point on the grid, instead you can simply track the index of the segment to turn. After each turn you increment the index to point it to the next segment, until you turned all segments, then you remove the TurningPoint. To demonstrate here a small code sample:

```
public struct TurningPoint {
    public int Index;
    public Vector2 Direction
}

private List<TurningPoint> _turningPoints = new List<TurningPoint>();

void Update(){
    // ...
    // It would be the same for all other directions
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && lastHitKey != KeyCode.S)
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SnakeHeadUp;
        lastHitKey = KeyCode.W;
        _direction = Vector2.up; 
        _turningPoints.Add(new TurningPoint(){
            Index = 0,
            Direction = _direction
        };
    }
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    // ...
    for(int i = 0;i < _turningPoints.Count;i++){
        TurningPoint p = _turningPoints[i]
        Transform segmentToTurn = _segments[p.Index];
        // We're in 2D so we rotate around the Z-Axis
        segmentToTurn.Rotate(0f, 0f, 90f);
        p.Index += 1;
        // because TurningPoint is a struct we need to write the changed index back to the list
        _turningPoints[i] = p;
    }
    // now we check if we need to remove the oldest turning point because all segments already passed it
    if(_turningPoints.Count > 0 && _turningPoints[0].Index >= _segments.Count){
        _turningPoints.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
void ResetState(){
    // ...
    _turningPoints.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Hey! This solution was 99% there, with a few bugs that I'll work through.

For example, the body parts will be extremely inconsistent interms of their rotation after a period of time, and the head sprite is completely bugged (but I managed to fix that).

However, this did give me a new idea of how to fix this problem. So I thank you for that!